# Getting Too few arguments to function

Tags: symfony, sylius

hello i have extend and costumize the checkout to an one page checkout, in previous interation i have do the same and it work normally but when i try to do the same in new project sylius 1.10 it show me a probel that i havent found solution this is the one page checkout form:

```
$builder
    ->add('address', AddressType::class, [
        'data' => $options['order'],
        'customer' => $options['customer'],
    ])
    ->add('shipping', SelectShippingType::class, [
        'data' => $options['order'],
    ])
    ->add('payment', SelectPaymentType::class, [
        'data' => $options['order'],
    ])
    ->add('complete', CompleteType::class, [
        'data' => $options['order'],
    ])
```

and this is the error that i got:

> Too few arguments to function
> Sylius\Bundle\ResourceBundle\Form\Type\AbstractResourceType::__construct(),
> 0 passed in C:\wamp64\www\project\vendor\symfony\form\FormRegistry.php
> on line 89 and at least 1 expected

does the error is in the SelectPaymentType Only?

Comment: Your form extends AbstractResourceType which requires 2 arguments passed to it's constructor - the data class and the validations groups, make sure you pass those arguments.